# Is there any way to speed up time in Animal Crossing?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I am currently building my first house (just paid the downpayment) and waiting a full day to start designing my house is too long. Is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is known as **Time-Travelling**. It has some real benefits if you want to access different events/seasons/upgrades during the game, throughout the year.

There are two methods to do this. You can either adjust your 3DS clock, or adjust the in-game clock.

Select the method that best suits you and adjust the time/date accordingly:

1. On your 3DS, go to:

   System Settings > Other Settings > Date & Time > Today's Date or current Time.
2. In the Game, on main menu, go to:

   Continue > Select your "username" > "I need help first..." > "Set the date/time".

**Beware**, if you start time-travelling too much, you may miss villagers moving in and out, flowers/hybrids may become lost and you might find your town has more weeds than normal. Also, if you choose the 1st option, beware that adjusting your 3DS clock may have affects on your other games and applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's something called "time travelling". To time travel you have to do the following steps:

1. Choose "Continue" on the main menu in the game
2. Select the character that you want to play as
3. When Isabelle starts up your game, choose the "I need help first...." option.
4. Choose "Set the time" and then you just change the time and that's when you time travel!

Hope this helps!

Let me know if this doesn't work or the answer is wrong

[More info here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Travel)

Answer (score 0):

You log in as you then say to Isabelle I need help first and set your time.

Just to note :   If you time travel back everything will be the same as when you time traveled.

And:  You are at your own risk of losing a villager it may be your favorite.

Comment: This does not add any relevant information that the other two upvotes answers don't already state in greater detail. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.